# using live data and mvvm to assign listener to your view

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am having the following xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/to_textedit"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.openTimePickerClicked()}"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="10:00 pm"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and I am using view model to assign it is click listener as following

```
    val openTimePickerClickEvent = LiveEvent<Unit>()
fun openTimePickerClicked() {
        openTimePickerClickEvent.call()
    }
```

and in my model I bind this observer as following

```
private val openTimePickerClicked = Observer<Unit> {

            openTimePickerDialog () // here is the problem
        }

private fun openTimePickerDialog(textInputEditText : TextInputEditText) {

            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

            val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)

                textInputEditText.setText(SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time))
            }

            TimePickerDialog(
                binding.root.context,
                timeSetListener,
                cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                false
            ).show()
        }
```

how can I path the view to my method in the view to be able to set the text of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily set the listener in a method which you have set in XML.
Please follow below steps:

Define callback/listener in ViewModel like below:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel{
private MyCustomCallback callback;
...
public void doOnClick(MyCustomCallback mCallback){
    boolean isSuccessful = doMyAction.execute();
    if (isSuccessful){
        mCallback.actionIsSuccessful();
    } else {
        mCallback.actionFailed();
    }
}
...
public void setCallback(callback){
    this.callback = callback;   
}
public MyCustomCallback getCallback(){
    return this.callback;   
}
...

public interface MyCustomCallback{
    void actionIsSuccessful();
    void actionFailed();
}}
```

Now you have set this listener/Callback in XML like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/to_textedit"
                android:onClick="@{() -> ViewModel.doOnClick(ViewModel.callback)}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="10:00 pm"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now You have to set listener in the main activity. like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
...
private MyCustomCallback callback;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    callback = new MyViewModel.MyCustomCallback{
        @Override
        public void actionIsSuccessful(){
            //do something when action is successful
        }
        @Override
        public void actionFailed(){
            //do something when action fails
        }
    }
    viewModel.setCallback(callback);
}
```

}

Hope! this code will help you.
Happy coding...